# How to filter a vaex dataset by a list of numbers/categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vaex

As an example, I have the next dataset (fake random data) -

| Index | category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | 5 |
| 2 | cat | 22 |
| 3 | Tasselled Wobbegong | 44 |
| 4 | cat | 66 |
| 5 | Tasselled Wobbegong | 5 |
| 6 | dog | 23 |

I have this in a vaex dataframe.
Now imagine I have 10,000 categories not only 3.
I want to filter my vaex dataframe by a list of categories.
like so:

```
filter_category_list = ['cat','dog']
df = df[df.category in filter_category_list ]
```

(the code above doesn't work I imagine it would be similar to this)
I expect my output to be:

| Index | category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | 5 |
| 2 | cat | 22 |
| 4 | cat | 66 |
| 6 | dog | 23 |

Any idea how to achieve that **with vaex?**

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some solutions for that.

```
df.query("category in @filter_category_list")
```

```
df[df['category'].apply(lambda x: x in filter_category_list)]
```

```
df[df['category'].isin(filter_category_list)]
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `df.query` in vaex; `apply` is greatly discouraged unless absolutely necessary. The final suggestion about using `isin` is the correct approach for this case!